# Including a link in reponse.write

Tags: javascript, node.js

When I run the following code:

```
res.write("Author: ");
res.write("<a href='" + tweet[i].Link + "' target='_blank'>" + tweet[i].Lable + "</a> \n");
res.write("Date: " + tweet[i].TDate  + "\n");
```

I got this:

```
Author: <a href='https://twitter.com/esti_palombo' target='_blank'>esti_palombo</a> 
Date: 2016-03-12T00:00:00.000Z
Author: <a href='https://twitter.com/AbdElrazek_Esam' target='_blank'>AbdElrazek_Esam</a> 
Date: 2016-03-08T00:00:00.000Z
```

As you can see, the links do not work

But when I remove the first line `res.write("Author: ");` :

```
esti_palombo Date: 2016-03-12T00:00:00.000Z AbdElrazek_Esam Date: 2016-03-08T00:00:00.000Z
```

links are working fine but the new line `\n` does not work !!

Can someone help me with this

Answer (score 2):

By refusing to write a proper header, you're forcing the browser to guess it for you. As you can see, simply changing the format of your data is making it guess differently.

Set the content type to `text/html` and you'll be in the second case of your post, and since you're writing HTML you don't use newlines to break lines, you use paragraphs or line breaks (`<br>`).

Answer (score 0):

Please try by replacing '\n' with  `<br/>`